# How to append data to different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm getting data via ajax request & i want to append that data into two different div here is how i get data

```
$.get("/ajax/graph?param="+item.datapoint[0]).done(function(result){  $("#graf").html(result); })
```

this above code get me data in response like shown below

```
<div class="media">
<p>example</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>example 2</p>
</div>
```

Now i want to append class media part into a div that `div id="a1"`
and div class="content" into `div id="a2"`

How can i achieve this?

Comment: use `$('#a1').append(html)` method

Comment: then it will append all the response into a1 div

Comment: yes but you have condition based on you want to append

Comment: `$('.media').appendTo('#a1'); $('.content').appendTo('#a2');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use  [$.parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to convert the result string into an array of html elements and append each one of them to the corresponding div.

```js
var result= '<div class="media"><p>example</p></div><div class="content"><p>example 2</p></div>';
html = $.parseHTML(result);
$('#a1').append(html[0]);
$('#a2').append(html[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1"></div>
<div id="a2"></div>
```